# How to update image data?

Tags: php, html, crud

I am working on a page that has a crud table and I am stuck on the update function.

Everything is updating and working apart from the image.

```
    if(isset($_POST['update_player']))
    {
        $player_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['player_id']);
        $Photo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name']);
        $ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Id']);
        $Fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Fname']);
        $Lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Lname']);
        $Age = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Age']);
        $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Email']);
        $Phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Phone']);
        
        $query = "UPDATE players SET Photo='$Photo', ID='$ID', Fname='$Fname', Lname='$Lname' , Age = '$Age' , Email = '$Email' , Phone = '$Phone' WHERE id='$player_id' ";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    
        if($query_run)
        {   
            $_SESSION['message'] = "player Updated Successfully";
            header("Location: stam.php");
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "player Not Updated";
            header("Location: stam.php");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, be warned that the given `UPDATE`  query is widely open for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving the image to your "uploads" directory using [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), then store the file name or url in database. You should definitely take measures to protect yourself when saving user uploaded files. For example by checking the file extension to allow only images.

See simple guide on https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

**HTML**

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="Photo" id="Photo">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```php
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["Photo"]["name"]);
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// check $imageFileType here to be jpeg, jpg, bmp, png, gif etc
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["Photo"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

**SQL**

```php
$query = "UPDATE players SET Photo='$target_file', ID='$ID', Fname='$Fname', Lname='$Lname' , Age = '$Age' , Email = '$Email' , Phone = '$Phone' WHERE id='$player_id' ";
```